# How do you do an SSH Tunnel on a Mac?

Tags: tunnel

OK so I do this from a Linux box all the time. The command I use looks like this:

```
autossh -f -N -q -L 127.0.0.1:${PORT}:127.0.0.1:${PORT} targetmachine
```

We weren't able to get autossh to work and we can't get the regular client to work either from the command line. The idea is that our young Jedi is going to use a tunnel to get from his apartment out at the university to our home machine. He uses a Mac Book Pro, Siera. The above command was set up a long time ago and is just used for tunneling Synergy but we want to do something else. In particular he wants to forward some traffic such that his perspective changes from where he is to where we are. In other words, we'll probably be using the IP of the server's network card rather than localhost.

Clues? The parameters aren't even the same for autossh on a mac.

Comment: have you tried a syntax more like the one described here? http://www.revsys.com/writings/quicktips/ssh-tunnel.html A tunnel should have two endpoints, one local and one remote.

Comment: What we are trying to do is forward some torrent traffic around some ignorant and draconian rules. No, we are not trying to scam on anyone or do something we aren't supposed to. It's our paid-for bandwidth. Having said that what we want is to foward uTorrent to my home machine.